# scons env.InstallAs() doesn't seem to copy any file?

Tags: build, installation, scons

For example, I've a .c file as below:

$cat hello.c

```
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Then I use scons to build and copy it to some place:

$cat SConstruct

```
import os,sys
env = Environment()
hello = env.Program('hello.c')
env.InstallAs('/home/admin/hello-new', hello)
```

run scons under user named 'admin' it prints:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gcc -o hello.o -c hello.c
gcc -o hello hello.o
scons: done building targets.
```

Then I tried to "ls /home/admin" there's no such a thing like "hello-new". So I wonder why my "env.InstallAs()" worked at all? How to trouble-shoot and fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer to this is in the FAQ on the scons.org website.. Please consider joining the users mailing list and/or bringing questions to the IRC channel..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the FAQ, this is a common misunderstanding about SCons and thus in the FAQ:

https://scons.org/faq.html#How_do_I_install_files.3F_The_Install.28.29_method_doesn.27t_do_anything._In_general.2C_how_do_I_build_anything_outside_my_current_directory.3F

With your example changing to this should cause it to always build the target in question:

```
import os,sys
env = Environment()
hello = env.Program('hello.c')
install_target = env.InstallAs('/home/admin/hello-new', hello)

# Always build the install target by default
Default(install_target)
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually it didn't answer my problem.

Comment: The reason that target was never evaluated is by default scons only builds targets under the current directory. Since you're trying to install somewhere else scons doesn't think you're requesting it.  The simplest way to resolve is (See addition above).

Comment: Pretty sure it is indeed your issue, but perhaps you don't understand the why